# Why would I use an Android local service for a background networking task?

Tags: java, android, networking, service

I am writing an Android application which establishes a "semi-permanent" TCP socket connection, i.e. the connection should always be established when the application is visible but can be closed when it is not visible.

Currently, the connection is handled in a thread. The connection is only needed in one activity.

I am wondering what would be the advantages of putting the networking thread into an Android local service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to fetch data from the connection in background when app is not visible, then there is no benefit in putting in into a service.

Comment: I see. What if I wanted to access the connection from a second activity in the future? I guess it would be wiser to use a local service then, right?

Comment: @tajmahal even in this case it might be easier to share resource between activities rather than manage a service.